# Android ListView with Simple Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I created `ListView` activity to list some data retrieved from server.

Here is that **ListAtmActivity**.

```
public class ListAtmActivity extends ListActivity{

private static String url ="http://10.0.2.2:8080/hello/AvailabilityResponse";

private static final String ATM_NO = "atmbrno";
private static final String ATM_PLACE = "atmbrname";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);


    String brName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");


    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONArray contacts = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url,brName);

    try{

        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json_data = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String atm_id = json_data.getString(ATM_NO);
            String atm_name = json_data.getString(ATM_PLACE);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(ATM_NO, atm_id);
            map.put(ATM_PLACE, atm_name);

            contactList.add(map);                
        }                       
    }

    catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_main,
            new String[] { ATM_NO, ATM_PLACE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name , R.id.email });

    setListAdapter(adapter); 

    //setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

}}
```

My contact array is like this.

```
{"atmbrname":"ANURADAPURA [ATM 2]","atmbrno":"ATM084"},
{"atmbrname":"MANNAR BRANCH ","atmbrno":"ATM344"}
```

Here my two xml file also.

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
    <!-- Description label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But I can't get list view. No errors came. I think problem with my xml files. can anyone help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Yes..It's blank black Screen..Just the app name is in it as a heading.

Comment: try switching the layouts, i.e setContentView (R.layout.list_main) and inflate the list_item.xml

Comment: put this in your listview  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" or 
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Are you sure you have something in the `contactList`?

Comment: @Luksprog- yes..data are there.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the height to "match_parent". But not sure if that fixes your problem.

I only had problems with ListActivity, therefore I am using always a normal Activity and retrieve the ListView from the Contentview of the activity.